# C# converter object em object[]

Tags: c#

tenho o seguinte código:

```
var pagamento = new PefService.Pagamento();
pagamento.IdPagamentoCliente = "teste";

......

//resquest.Pagamentos é PefService.Pagamento[]
request.Pagamentos = pagamento; //error
```

Estou com o seguinte erro

> Connot implicitly convert type 'Pagamento' to 'Pagamento[]'

Comment: A sua pergunta traz uma duvida o que é `request` e o que tem em `Pagamentos`, não adianta passar só o tipo, precisa mostrar se tem instância e posições no `array`

Comment: O request.Pagamentos é um list ? Mostra o resto do código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de você fazer é a seguinte:

```
var pagamentos = new List<PerfService.Pagamento>(); 
pagamentos.Add(new PerfService.Pagamento() {
    IdPagamentoCliente = "Teste",
});

request.Pagamentos = pagamentos.ToArray();
```

Cada pagamento você pode adicionar a esta lista.